# Dynamically reboot server periodically using cronjob

Tags: dynamic, cron, server, reboot, periodicity

I need my server to reboot after every 5 days of uptime
if it is not rebooted and again reboot after exactly  5 days and continue this process consecutively.
I would like to know how to do this with cronjob or any other script

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dow, or Day of Week, part of the crontab syntax, to execute the command on every occurrence of a particular day, using numbers in the form:

> 0-6 Sunday to Saturday
>
> 1-7 Monday to Sunday

Or even shortened word notation such as `WED` or `THU` for Wednesday or Thursday

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00 07 * * 5 your-command-here
```

The example above would run the command at 7:00 am every Friday